# What happens when a C Function Yields a Python Coroutine, and then tries to return to it?

Tags: python, c++, c, coroutine

I can't find anything about this situation in Python. In my current setup I have a C function that is currently profiled to take some time to process, and will block execution. I plan on using a task system to handle events.

I am still debating between using Lua or Python. I know what will happen in Lua under this circumstance. Where Lua will push data onto it's stack, and then resume with the "resume" function passing back all data. But I don't know what will happen in python.

If I were to call the C function in python, and then yield the task's execution, what would happen when I try to return data to the yielded coroutine? And how would I do that?